# What is the most distant object from the Earth that a spacecraft has visited to date?

Tags: astronomy, space-mission, solar-system-exploration

What is the most distant object from the earth that a spacecraft visited has visited so far? What was the mission and when did it happen?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Depending on your definition of "object," Neptune is currently the farthest. It was visited by Voyager 2 in 1989. New Horizons will be visiting Pluto in 2015

If by object you mean cosmic structure though, then Voyager 1 is currently in the Heliosheath and is expected to reach the heliopause by 2015. These are regions that describe interactions between the sun's solar wind and the interstellar medium.

Comment: Had Voyager 2 really visited Pluto? Or just crossed its orbit?

Comment: Just crossed it's orbit

Answer (score 11):

We landed on Titan in 2004.
That is definitely a milestone in being far away and landing on the surface of something big.
[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens_%28spacecraft%29)

It's a damn shame they didn't manage to get a better photograph of the surface.

Comment: Welcome to Astronomy and thanks for your input! I think this answer has potential value, but whilst this may provide access to relevant information [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: +1 for "landed" as a fair interpretation of "visited"...